# Where can I find IE10 with following user string: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; EIE10;ENUSMSE; rv:11.0) like Gecko"?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser

Actually I have got to know that there is some html problems only in browser with this user string. I had done some googling over there but not find much about it except getting that this is "Enhanced Internet Explorer 10".

Comment: I wonder if it's an experimental build.